# manage roster for ejabberd, mod_roster_odbc or other option? mod_roster_odbc is nowhere to be found?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Try to manage rosters of ejabberd from a webapp, using rest module.

Everywhere it states manage roster for ejabberd, mod_roster_odbc is the way to go.
But i cannot find this module anywhere online!

Is this mod_roster_odbc still the way to go?
Where to download it? Its not in the ejabberd module repo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with mod_roster_odbc you can store and manage your roster with external database like mysql mssql ...
ejabberd use mnesia database as default so mod_roster store your roster in mnesia so if you want to use mod_roster_odbc you can search "use ejabberd with native mysql".

Comment: for mod_roster_odbc you dont need to add modules in ejabberd.simply change the line "{mod_roster}" to "{mod_roster_odbc}" in ejabberd config file